# Add Windows Firewall rule for multiple IP's using netsh.exe

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-firewall, netsh, firewall-rules

```bash
echo@
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="test" dir=in action=block protocol=TCP remoteip=16.24.0.0/24,**from 157.175.0.0 to 157.175.255.255**,**from 15.184.0.0 to 15.184.255.255**,**from 15.185.0.0 to 15.185.255.255**
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="test" dir=out action=block protocol=TCP remoteip=16.24.0.0/24,**from 157.175.0.0 to 157.175.255.255**,**from 15.184.0.0 to 15.184.255.255**,**from 15.185.0.0 to 15.185.255.255**
start wf.msc
pause
```

I'm trying create a Windows batch file which can block IP addresses in my firewall.

It's working when I use one IP, but I need to block ranges, not only one. For example the range `15.185.0.0` to `15.185.255.255`.

Comment: I found the syntax for IP range, you can use dash (-) for example 157.175.0.0-157.175.255.255

Comment: Your example code showed that you wanted to include multiple ranges, but the comment above shows your solution for just one. Could you please use the answer area to submit a full solution for your shown problem code. _You could even mark it as your accepted answer._

Comment: BTW, do you know what `157.175.0.0/16`, `15.184.0.0/16`, and `15.185.0.0/16` mean? Read up on CIDR, _(Classless Inter-Domain Routing)_, notation, to learn more.

Comment: @Compo thank you so much for let me know what is CIDR, BTW i tried to make all these IP's use /24 but It's didn't work and now I know why, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

this is the answer to my question

```bash
echo@
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="example" dir=in action=block protocol=TCP remoteip=16.24.0.0/24,157.175.0.0-157.175.255.255,15.184.0.0-15.184.255.255,15.185.0.0-15.185.255.255
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="example" dir=out action=block protocol=TCP remoteip=16.24.0.0/24,157.175.0.0-157.175.255.255,15.184.0.0-15.184.255.255,15.185.0.0-15.185.255.255
start wf.msc
pause
```